# Новая схема публикации новых версий приложений в AppStore?

Tags: ios, apple, appstore

Сегодня, залив новую версию приложения обнаружил, что не могу добавить её в кабинете разработчика - появились новые статусы (картинка).
Сколько по времени теперь проходит данная процедура? И зачем её ввел Apple?

До этого всегда в окне "Добавить сборку" сразу после заливки новой версии, она была доступна сразу...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сколько себя помню всегда так было. может занять пару часов. И попробуйте выйти на другой экран и вернуться - может не обновляется страница нормально.

Comment: Так в том-то и дело, залил новую версию часов 9 тому назад. Потом с периодичностью несколько часов - еще две версии (видно из скрина). Всё тот же статус... версия текущая крашится, поэтому хочу очень быстро сменить на новую исправленную...

Comment: заливал версию на прошлой неделе, часа два она была в обработке. Сейчас видимо все кинулись заливать версии под tvOS, может по этому так долго.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928471/my-prerelease-app-has-been-processing-for-over-a-week-in-itunes-connect-what

Comment: Спасибо. Понятно одно, надо подождать.

Comment: если там комментарии посмотрите, кто то сказал загружать новые версии пока одна не проскочит. Видимо у них там что то зависает/крэшится.

Comment: Есть какие то новости?

Comment: Да, еще через несколько часов стал доступен выбор новой версии. Все последующие, вновь залитые - становились доступны сразу же.

Comment: публикуйте ответ. хорошая информация